# Is it weird to visit a scientific conference as an undergraduate student?

Tags: research-process, conference, undergraduate

I'm an undergraduate (Bachelor's) student and I'm thinking about attending a conference which exactly matches the topic of a research project that I'm working on at the moment. I have never attended a real conference.

I wouldn't go to present anything, but just because I have a great personal interest in the topic and because I would like to know about the recent developments. Would it be weird if I attend this conference alone? It is a small conference but there is a special student's price, which makes me think that I might be welcome.

Comment: No it's not weird. Go! People will probably appreciate you being there, and try to "lure" or "mold" you in some way (and i mean that in a positive way).

Comment: Not at all! I did that sometimes when I was an undergraduate. No one thought I was an undergraduate :D.

Answer (score 9):

> Would it be weird if I attend this conference alone?

Probably, as an undergraduate, you won't be able to connect too much with the more senior researchers, but there's nothing weird at all. So, if you can, go for it, and enjoy your first conference!

Comment: In particular, if there is a poster session, go to it and talk with people. You might even find a future graduate advisor that way...

Answer (score 3):

No, not at all. In many large conferences there are events specifically tailored for undergraduates, including poster competitions. You may find it easier to connect to other attending undergrads or graduate students. However, I would not discount the benefit of even being a passive spectator and just attending and getting the feel of presenting at a conference. Information such as the format and style of presentations, the questions people may ask, and experience of good and bad presentations will be helpful. All of this will come in handy when you do actually have to present as a graduate student.

Answer (score 3):

> a conference which exactly matches the topic of a research project that I'm working on at the moment

If there is one reason why you should attend the conference you refer to, it is right here.

You MUST go.

You might be able to ask questions you might have on your topic, get acquainted with others who are interested and working on the same topic, network with them in person and on linkedin/researchgate, etc.

Actually, there are too many reasons why you should definitely attend and none against it.